# How do I indent my code in Emacs by 4 spaces intead of 2 for a bunch of files?

Tags: emacs, formatting

What is a more sane, automatic solution to tabbing my code by 4 spaces for a bunch of files? How do I make sure that tabify does not affect perldoc?

Comment: What do you mean?  Do you want to reformat existing code, ie to replace tabs with spaces, or to change the size of tabs?

or do you want to have your code automatically indent itself?

Comment: Or do you accept solutions outside emacs? Like a shell script for example

Comment: A shell script is fine. I want to reformat exisitng code where in some places I used two spaces as indentation when I really want four.

Comment: I found a solution:
M-x tabify scans the region for sequences of spaces, and converts sequences of at least three spaces to tabs 

But I want it to be at least two spaces

Comment: Actually it might be two characters. How do I select all the text to tabify?

Answer (score 4):

Well, you'll need this

```
(setq-default tab-width 4)
```

Then

```
C-x h
M-x indent-region
```

This sounds very similar to this [other stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717177/how-can-i-apply-a-new-emacs-c-style-to-reformat-all-my-source-files).

Comment: It seems to not intepret perldoc effectively causing the =<something> to be indented as well

Comment: Correct, I can't find anything others have written which handles indentation ignoring perldoc (or at least treating it special).  Kind of surprising...

Answer (score 2):

I had massive issues with this: This is the solution I came up with for a 3-spaces rule.

```
;;;; Tab settings ;;;;
;Tab width is 3
(setq tab-width 3)
;Tab width is 3 by default..
(setq-default tab-width 3)
;Use spaces always.
(setq indent-tabs-mode nil)
;Jump by 3.
(setq c-basic-offset 3)
;this defaulted to 4 and had to be reset to 3. 
(setq perl-indent-level 3)
;Tab stop list out to col 60
;Manually set by x3
(setq tab-stop-list '(3 6 9 12 15 18 21 24 27 30 33 36 39 42 45 48 51 54 57 60))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look up the documentation for the mode you are using (e.g. Lisp mode, C mode, Perl mode) for setting up the desired indentation and for reindenting a region (e.g. in SLIME, this is done with `C-M-\`).

Answer (score 0):

[My cperl-mode](http://github.com/jrockway/cperl-mode) seems to indent (or rather, not indent) POD fine, as long as it has a newline before the `=head1` or `=pod`.  `perlpod` says:

> Without that empty line before the "=head1", many translators wouldn't have recognized the "=head1" as starting a Pod block.