# Apply a Built-in Style to a file with Emacs

Tags: emacs, code-formatting

I've a c file written like this:

```
int main(void){

}
```

I would like to change every bracket in the file according to the "linux" format.

```
int main(void)
{

}
```

How can I do this with Emacs?

EDIT 1:

This is my .emacs file:

```
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(ansi-color-faces-vector
   [default default default italic underline success warning error])
 '(custom-enabled-themes (quote (tango-dark)))
 '(inhibit-startup-screen t)
 '(package-archives
   (quote
    (("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/")
     ("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")))))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )

(setq make-backup-files nil) ; stop creating backup~ files
(setq auto-save-default nil) ; stop creating #autosave# files
(setq c-default-style "linux"
      c-basic-offset 4)
```

EDIT 2:

Solved by creating an emacs macro that calls GNU indent.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I apply a new Emacs C style to reformat all my source files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717177/how-can-i-apply-a-new-emacs-c-style-to-reformat-all-my-source-files)

Answer (score 1):

Primary source of how to do this is the [emacs wiki page](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IndentingC). To use `linux` style in emacs:

```el
(setq c-default-style "linux")
```

put the above line in your ~/.emacs or ~/.config/emacs/config if you have xdg paths defined for emacs.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>M</kbd><kbd>\</kbd> will reindent an arbitrary region, so after you set the c-default-style to linux simply select the content of the buffer and re-indent. More on this at [CC-Mode manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ccmode/)

Comment: But this will be applied only when I write a new file

Comment: Using Ctrl-M-\ it only corrects the indentation but not the brackets position